# how to use the b = [[1]*3]*3 in a proper way?

Tags: python, variables, evaluation

All,

code:

```
#=A===================
>>> b = [[1]*3]*3
>>> b 
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> b[0][0] = 0                 
>>> b
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
>>> 
#=B===================
>>> b = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> b[0][0] = 0
>>> b
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

1. Can I use the format may looks like **"b = [[1]*3]*3"** to get the same behavior as the **"b = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]"** to reduce type in?
2. as **"b = [[1]*3]*3"** may return a "reference" based list, is it useful for daily works? any sample?

Thanks!
KC

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but your question gives me a headache :D Could you please rephrase ?

Comment: The two expressions do different things.  Clearly, you can't use `b = [[1]*3]*3`  as your example proves.  Since you've given a good proof that it won't work, what's your question?

Comment: @S.Lott, this problem came from read post on web, when I read code "b = [[1]*3]*3", I think this expression is clearly and directly enough may reduce type in, but I am sure it is not able to work, yes, i understand it is a "reference" list, so I think is it possible to refine it and works same as "b = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]" to reduce type in, and as "b = [[1]*3]*3" may result as a "reference" based list, is it useful for daily works?

Comment: @user478514: Your example proves that `b = [[1]*3]*3` cannot work same as `b = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`.  Since you have created absolute proof that the two cannot ever work the same, what more do you want?

Comment: @S.Lott, as I said the "b = [[1]*3]*3" may looks easy to type than "b = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]", so what I need is an expression which buddies on below have given the answer "b = [[1]*3 for _ in range(3)]", more over, since "b = [[1]*3]*3" is also a grammar valid expression then I guess it may useful somehow...

Comment: @user478514: `b = [[1]*3]*3` may useful somehow?  So?  What's the question?  You've proven that it cannot be used for what you want.  You have created a very good proof.  What more do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it references the same list, so when you do `b[0][0] = 0`, you are really updating the value at the reference(in which all three arrays point to).

To get the desired results, I would do(using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

```
>>> b = [[1]*3 for _ in range(3)]
>>> b
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> b[0][0] = 0
>>> b
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

which actually recreates a list, so it references different lists, rather than the same one in your answer.

`b = [[1]*3 for _ in range(3)]` is equivalent to:

```
b = []
for _ in range(3):
  b.append([1]*3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build your list with a list comprehension instead:

```
b = [[1]*3 for _ in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `[[1, 1, 1]] * 3` creates a list of three references to the same `[1, 1, 1]` list. To do what you want, you have to create copies of [1, 1, 1] using `list()` or using slice notation:

```
first_list = [1, 1, 1]
second_list = [first_list[:], first_list[:], first_list[:]]
```

or

```
second_list = [list(first_list), list(first_list), list(first_list)]
```

To do the above in one line, you could do this:

```
second_list = [[1] * 3 for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

At section A:
you have a list with 3 items, but all items points to one object:

> [1]*3

like this:

```
a = [1,1,1]
b = [a,a,a]
```

But at the section B , you have a list with different items